# Access Meteor.user() inside vue router in vue-meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, vue.js, vue-router

I am currently using meteor-vue: https://github.com/meteor-vue/

I am trying to access Meteor.user() inside the router since my users have roles, and certain roles can access certain components.

But the value is always undefined, is there a solution for this?

```
factory.addRoutes([

     {
        path: "/",
        name: "mainComponent",
        component: MainComponent,
        beforeEnter: (to,from,next) =>{
            console.log(Meteor.user())  //undefined
            if(Meteor.user().role=="admin")
                {
                    next({name:"adminPage"});
                }
        }
]
```

​This is what I am trying to do. Please help.

Thank you.​

Comment: It may take a few cycles for `Meteor.user()` to become available via pub-sub. Your routes need to show a spinner during loading.